# Не удается установить maven 3.8.1

Tags: java, apache, maven

Решил установить новую версию maven 3.8.1, раньше была 3.6.0
После установки с помощью chocolatey maven перестал работать и в ошибке ищет струю версию, хотя переменные среды прописаны на версию 3.8.1
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема
Скрины прилагаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод команды `echo $PATH`  запущенной из консоли.

Comment: а файл, который указан в ошибке реально существует?

Comment: Это старая версия, я её удалил и указал путь системных переменных до новой версии. Но всё равно запрашивается старая версия при "mvn -v"